# Heroku is not recognizing my precompiled assets for rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I first switch to a separate `heroku_branch` branch to keep the precompiled assets from "poluting" my git repository then merge with the master repository

```
$ git checkout heroku_branch
$ git merge master
```

I've done exactly what heroku's documentation recommends with resepect to precompiling assets

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

/Users/bagvoo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /Users/bagvoo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@upvote/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
/Users/bagvoo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /Users/bagvoo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@upvote/bin/rake assets:precompile:nondigest RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets

$ git add .
$ git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"
```

Then I push to the heroku repository using

```
$ git push heroku master
```

However, I don't get

```
-----> Preparing Rails asset pipeline
       Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally
```

Instead I get:

```
----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
      Running: rake assets:precompile
      rake aborted!
      undefined method `blamed_files' for nil:NilClass
      (in /tmp/build_6x7f3k642z8z/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb)

      Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
      (See full trace by running task with --trace)
      Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
```

There is a `public/assets/manifest.yml` so I don't understand why heroku is trying to precompile these things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was pushing from the wrong branch.

### Was

```
$ git push heroku master
```

### Is

```
$ git push heroku heroku_branch:master
```

This is specific to the case above where you have a separate branch from the master branch that you are pushing from.